# Simplify the expression where $x>y>0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Simplify $$\frac{\sqrt {x^2+y^2}+x}{y+\sqrt {x^2-y^2}}\cdot\frac{x-\sqrt {x^2+y^2}}{\sqrt {x^2-y^2}-y}$$

Help please, I tried but the answer doesn't match. I did it by multiplying of course and then normally simplifying.

I tried and what came is $\dfrac{-2xy -y^2}{2xy + x^2}$ and the correct answer is $\dfrac{y^2}{2y^2-x^2}$

Comment: It would help if you posted your answer and the correct one.

Comment: Done. Check out the question.

Comment: Isn't it $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$?

Comment: Yup @ZaferCesur I didn't know how to do that, sorry!

Comment: Thanks for correcting it @ZaferCesur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{\sqrt {x^2+y^2}+x}{y+\sqrt {x^2-y^2}}\cdot\frac{x-\sqrt {x^2+y^2}}{\sqrt {x^2-y^2}-y}= \frac{x + \sqrt {x^2+y^2}}{\sqrt {x^2-y^2}+y}\cdot\frac{x-\sqrt {x^2+y^2}}{\sqrt {x^2-y^2}-y}$$

Now you've got a function of the form $$\dfrac{(a+b)(a- b)}{(c+d)(c- d)} = \dfrac{a^2 - b^2}{c^2 - d^2}$$

The rest is then simplification.

Comment: Um sorry but um disturbing you a lot! Just have a look at this link and explain me, someone answered it but I can't understand. :( http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20140202113143AATCbqm

Answer (score 1):

$(a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2$

So,

$[(\sqrt {x^2+y^2})+x]\cdot [x-(\sqrt {x^2+y^2})]=[x+(\sqrt {x^2+y^2})]\cdot [x-(\sqrt {x^2+y^2})]=x^2-(x^2+y^2)=-y^2$

Can you proceed?

Comment: If you're having trouble with these hairy expressions, let $a=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $b=x$

Comment: Yeah, I'll try. Wait. :)

Comment: Okay I guess you just solved the upper one right? @ZaferCesur

Comment: Yes, indeed. @Kiara

Comment: Alright @ZaferCesur